# How to get Spark Streaming running time

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I need to set up a Spark Streaming application. Jobs of the application need to make some decisions based on the whole application running time.

For example, assume the Spark Streaming application was submitted at 08:00. The jobs run between 08:00 and 10:00 should do a plus operation, while the jobs run after 10:00 should do a minus operation.

How can I record the first job's (or the application's) start time and determine the interval between each job and the first job? Or is there any other good solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SparkContext`'s [`startTime()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html#startTime--) method returns the time when it became active.